# SyntaxError: invalid syntax в Питоне 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал программу, которая загадывает число от 1 до введенного числа, и игроку надо его угадать, но на проверке введенного числа выдает SyntaxError. Что я делаю не так?

```
from random import randint

top = int(input('Input a highest possible number. '))
rand_number = randint(1, top)
attempt = 0
while 1 == 1:
    guess = (input('Input your guess. ')
    if 1 > guess or guess > top: # Если guess вне [1, top], отсюда начинаются ошибки.
        print('Are you giving up? Y/N ')
        answer = input()
        if answer in ['N', 'n', 'No', 'no', 'NO']:
            print("OK, we are back to the game!")
            continue
        else:
            print('GAME OVER')
            break
```

Comment: Надо `guess = int(input('Input your guess. '))` поставить, насколько я понимаю

Comment: оффтоп, вместо `while 1 == 1:` просто используйте `while True:` :) и сравнивайте текст регистронезависимо, а то напишет юзер `nO` и ваша проверка будет неуспешной, а можно сразу проверить регистронезависимо, приведя ответ в нижний регистр, и не париться: `if answer.lower() in ['n', 'no']:`

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`guess = (input('Input your guess. ')`
не хватает скобки

Comment: Наоборот, лишняя скобка же

Comment: все зависит от того что он хотел сделать) я думаю ему там не только скобки не хватает, а еще и int перед первой скобкой)

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

top = int(input('Input a highest possible number: '))
rand_number = randint(1, top)
attempt = 0

while True:
    guess = int(input('Input your guess: '))
    if guess not in range(1, top):
        answer = input('Are you giving up? Y/N ')
        if answer.lower() in ('n', 'no'):
            print("OK, we are back to the game!")
            continue
        elif answer.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
            print('GAME OVER')
            break
```

Comment: `guess = int(input('Input your guess. '))` и тут неправильно `if guess not in [1, top]:`, у автора какой-то диапазон проверяется

Comment: @gil9red Ой, джил спасибо! Я хотел улучшить и проморгал...

Comment: @gil9red ;) ...

Comment: @gil9red А, не, инт надо было сделать ...

Comment: @gil9red `и тут неправильно if guess not in [1, top]` -- почему, автор ж сам написал...

Comment: > if guess not in (1, top): Это же не будет работать, или нет?

Comment: @Andref буит, а что нет? Ну по идеи должно... ;)